# fplmr font is not created

Tags: mathpazo

I am compiling a latex file and I am getting the error

```
    kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+480/600 --dpi 480 fplmrmktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fplmr.
mktexpk: perhaps fplmr is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


 $ rpm -ql texlive-mathpazo|grep fpl
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/mathpazo/fplmb.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/mathpazo/fplmbb.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/mathpazo/fplmbi.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/mathpazo/fplmr.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/mathpazo/fplmri.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathpazo/fplmb.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathpazo/fplmbb.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathpazo/fplmbi.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathpazo/fplmr.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathpazo/fplmri.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmb.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmbb.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmbi.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmr.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmri.pfb
```

I do have the font as part of the mathpazo package.  I do not understand what entry might be missing from some kind of map file.

Comment: Maybe try running from the command line `initexmf -mkmaps` to refresh `dvips.map` & friends.

Comment: What is the output of `kpsewhich psfonts.map` and `grep fplmr $(kpsewhich psfonts.map)`? The font `fplmr` is a Type1 font used for math.

Comment: @bernard I do not have the initexmf command, and neither `initex` nor `inimf` recognize the `-mkmaps` option.

Comment: `$ kpsewhich psfonts.map
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
$ grep fplmr $(kpsewhich psfonts.map)
fplmr PazoMath <fplmr.pfb
fplmri PazoMath-Italic <fplmri.pfb`

Comment: Then try `updmap --admin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Guys.  Running simply `updmap` without any options did the job.